# Robolectric: how to test a SherlockActivity

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, robolectric, android-testing

I'm trying to run tests on an Activity which extends SherlockActivity. I read everything I could find about the solutions for testing activities with ActionBarSherlock and also tried following https://github.com/passy/absshadow-sample

this is what I'm currently doing:

**custom test runner:**

```
public class CustomTestRunner extends RobolectricTestRunner {
    private static final int SDK_INT = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

    public CustomTestRunner(Class<?> testClass) throws InitializationError {
        super(testClass);
        addClassOrPackageToInstrument("com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity");
    }

    @Override
    protected void bindShadowClasses() {
        super.bindShadowClasses();
        Robolectric.bindShadowClass(ShadowSherlockActivity.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTest(final Method method) {
        final int targetSdkVersion = robolectricConfig.getSdkVersion();
        setStaticValue(Build.VERSION.class, "SDK_INT", targetSdkVersion);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTest(final Method method) {
        resetStaticState();
    }

    @Override
    public void resetStaticState() {
        setStaticValue(Build.VERSION.class, "SDK_INT", SDK_INT);
    }
}
```

**shadow SherlockActivity:**

```
@Implements(SherlockActivity.class)
public class ShadowSherlockActivity extends ShadowActivity {

    @Implementation
    public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
        super.setContentView(layoutResID);    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Implementation
    public ActionBar getSupportActionBar() {
        return new ActionBar() {
            // removed for readability
        };
    }
}
```

for some reason its aways failing with this:

```
WARNING: you probably should have called setContentView() first
java.lang.Exception: Stack trace
    at java.lang.Thread.dumpStack(Thread.java:1342)
    at     com.xtremelabs.robolectric.shadows.ShadowActivity.findViewById(ShadowActivity.java:183)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.bytecode.ShadowWrangler.methodInvoked(ShadowWrangler.java:99)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.bytecode.RobolectricInternals.methodInvoked(RobolectricInternals.java:144)
    at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java)
    at com.dgti.ds.activities.ChooseLocationActivity.findViews(ChooseLocationActivity.java:44)
    at com.dgti.ds.activities.ChooseLocationActivity.onCreate(ChooseLocationActivity.java:34)
    at com.dgti.ds.activities.ChooseLocationActivityTests.shouldGetGoogleAPIKeyIfNull(ChooseLocationActivityTests.java:81)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:76)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:195)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

my activity does call `setContentView` first, before any `findViewById`.

the weird part is that no matter what I do in the shadow implementation of `setContentView`, nothing seems to happen (for example, throwing a `NullPojnterException`).
my shadow does get registered, as if I try to override the implementation of `onCreate` and throw the exception there, it does work.

what am I missing here ?

Answer (score 2):

apparently changing the Java SDK in Intellij's project settings to Oracle instead of OpenJDK fixed this issue for me.

Comment: I have same issue despite I'm using Oracle Java SDK, always got WARNING: you probably should have called setContentView() first
do you have another tip/fix ?